# Where can I find a decent tutorial/explanation of using Castle Validators with ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, castle-windsor

Where can I find a decent tutorial/explanation of using Castle Validators with ASP.NET MVC2?

I want to go with Castle because I'm not fond of the fact that I can't test my POCOs using Data Annotations without copying the logic of grabbing the attributes and calling isValid on all of them. I'm much more fond of the fact that with Castle I can  just call IsValid on the ValidatorRunner which I can instantiate in my tests. I might just forget about the built-in mvc2 validation framework and go with xVal. /shrug

Comment: shrug? What are you shrugging at?  You have a personal preference?

Comment: no personal preference, it's just upsetting that there seems to be such a giant documentation hole for something that would seem pretty common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These articles/screencast seems to be good:

- [ASP.NET MVC Auto Model Validation with xVal](http://blog.coreycoogan.com/tag/castle-validator/)
- [Model-based Client-side Validation for ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/04/30/model-based-client-side-validation-for-aspnet-mvc/)
- [Contact Form with ASP.NET MVC, Castle Validation, & fluentHtml](http://derans.blogspot.com/2010/03/contact-form-with-aspnet-mvc-castle.html)

Hope that helps.